# Microsoft Notation - Names of Namespaces

Tags: c#, architecture, namespaces, naming-conventions

Looking at [Names of Namespaces (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026(v=vs.110).aspx), it has the following code to show the recommended namespace structure:

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

Are my assumptions correct about this notation?

- `<...>` are like variables. For example `<Company>`, I replace with my own company name.
- `...|...` pipe character means choose the left or right side expression
- `(...)` parens are used for grouping expressions - nothing to do with optionality
- `[...]` is to say that something is optional.

Secondly, does this notation have a name I can google for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is a variation of [Backus-Naur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) syntax.

This notation is commonly used to express programming language grammar. It's actually extremely useful when specifying inputs, and I recommend reading up on it.

Comment: Ok, googling it and reading up, yes my notation summary is correct `:-)`. How would one specify inputs using it - can you give me a link?

Comment: @TahirHassan Perhaps I should have been clearer: By "inputs" I meant things like program arguments or commands. In other words, for specifying a grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumptions are correct, however these are only 'guidelines'
They don't have to be (and shouldn't IMO) be stuck to rigidly.

If I'm developing internal only, or "core" libraries, I'll sometimes (if agreed with the team) drop the `Company` part - You don't see `Microsoft.System.String` for example...

As far as I know, this notation doesn't have a name - it's only a set of guidelines.